# How to design a system for offline updates of Linux systems that use Debian's apt?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, apt

I'm developing an update / upgrade service with an offline SDK for Linux devices.

The idea is to replicate the update / upgrade Linux services into an offline device. The "offline" device is capable to reach "internet" but only  through message exchange using the SDK and through other devices (multi-hop). Devices are from different architectures, therefore the device that has "internet" capabilities (gateway) has to be capable to request and download the packages to be upgraded to/from a different architecture. the gateway device has to be capable to cache the downloaded requested packages from updates (to act as a CDN), avoiding repo requests.

The offline device doesn't have have IP address and the way it communicates is irrelevant, because the offline SDK guaranties internet reachability over multi-hop.

What I need - I need someone to provide me some help or guidance about the update / upgrade work flow on Linux.

What I found so far:

- **update**

  - update command loads the /etc/apt/sources.list
  - don't know how update resolves each line on /etc/apt/sources.list, it seems it has a function where it loads the "deb" a "link" and "arguments" that match the corresponding repo folders.
  - after that it starts to download all the corresponding "Packages" files in each resolved link.
- **upgrade**

  - makes a comparison between the updated local "Packages" files and the "Packages" files in the repo.

Is there any source code from update / upgrade available ?
I did some web search on the apt repos, but I couldn't find the update / upgrade functions.

Comment: How about you just setup your internet-capable device as a whitelist-based proxy server, or a local repository mirror? You don't have to program anything and you get a rock-solid, supported solution instead of a brittle home-made hack.

Comment: What about [this](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/1d9e29c9e2a5591b42a99a721b901fc003ed9149/apt-pkg/upgrade.cc) and [this](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/1d9e29c9e2a5591b42a99a721b901fc003ed9149/apt-pkg/update.cc)?

Comment: or you could consider to setup a internal repo, that specific `apt update / upgrade` would directly leads to `change on repo location` and `pull from your mirror sites`

Comment: @B... you may be interested in [Apt-Cacher NG](https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/).

Comment: I remember using a perl script done from a friend years ago to download the packages from the office and then install it at home, it was called `get-deb` or `get-deb.pl`. What about [apt-offline](https://github.com/rickysarraf/apt-offline)? For the proxy solution I'm currently using Debian's approx to share the downloaded .deb on multiple machines (debian and raspbian, it support repositories with different architectures)